# CMD xcopy команда с unicode символами работает в windows console но не работает в php

Tags: php, cmd

Я хочу использовать следующую команду .

```
xcopy "E:\Dropbox\dbstore\15957_тест_директ.fbx" "E:\Dropbox\dbstore\test\15957_тест_директ.fbx"
```

Когда я использую эту команду в console, то все работает нормально, но когда вызываю из `php`,  файл не копируется.

```
$command="echo f | xcopy "E:\Dropbox\dbstore\15957_тест_директ.fbx" "E:\Dropbox\dbstore\test\15957_тест_директ.fbx";

$result=exec($command,$out2,$ret2);
```

Я получаю `out=0 File(s) copied ret=4` . 
Хочу заметить, что когда я вызываю эту команду из console, все не латинские символы замениваются `?`, но файл копируется и все работает прекрасно.
Что можно сделать, чтобы решить проблему с utf8 символами?

Comment: Много кавычек у вас или мало) смотря как посмотреть - (1)"echo f | xcopy (2)"E:\Dropbox\dbstore\15957_тест_директ.fbx(3)" (4)"E:\Dropbox\dbstore\test\15957_тест_директ.fbx(5)";

Answer (score 0):

```
$command= '"echo f | xcopy "E:\Dropbox\dbstore\15957_тест_директ.fbx" "E:\Dropbox\dbstore\test\15957_тест_директ.fbx"';

$command = iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$command);

$result = exec($command,$out2,$ret2);
```

Comment: Спасибо, что исправили, но проблема в том, что имя файла состоит из русских букв, потому что когда я вызываю ту же команду для файла латинским именем , все работает.

Comment: исправил свой ответ, попробуйте так

Comment: Я попробовал `$command = iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$command);`, но имя файла стало `15995_С‚РµСЃС‚_РґРёСЂРµРєС‚2`, и копию не сделал.